# Ubuntu does not boot to desktop

Tags: boot, networking, raspberrypi, hvr-2250

I installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 and it was working fine until after couple of restarts. Now, it no longer boots to a desktop environment. I get this black screen with login:

[image: Ubuntu login (no DE)]

After entering the password it enters a directory and not the desktop.

I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: What exactly have you done since you first installed Ubuntu? Did you uninstall or modify packages needed by the desktop environment?

Comment: Try the command `startx`. If it does not boot to desktop post the output. Also try the following, connect to internet with USB tethering from a mobile phone, and enter the command `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`. Then reboot.

Comment: You have tagged raspberrypi although you seem to be using a laptop. Is Raspberry Pi somehow relevant to this?